# Change Default Print Page Setup in Portable Firefox

Tags: firefox, portability, portable-applications, firefox-5

In portable Firefox 5 when you print there is the "Page Setup" that allows you to enable print background colors and a tab to change "Margins & Header/Footer".

**The questions is:** This only seems to save for the current session and reverts back to a default each time you close and reopen portable firefox. Is there a way to change these defaults so they don't need to be customized each time? I would like to have the "Headers & Footers" all set to --blank-- as the default and "Print Background (colors and images) set to checked as the default.

*EDIT:* I found the about:config and can make the Header & Footer changes in there but again I lose those changes after restarting. I am not seeing the print background colors in here though.

Any ideas?

Comment: I found the part to edit Header & Footer added these lines to the default prefs.js in Data/Profile Still haven't found the background color part  
`user_pref("print.print_headerleft", "")  user_pref("print.print_headercenter", "")  user_pref("print.print_headerright", "")  
user_pref("print.print_footerleft", "");  
user_pref("print.print_footercenter", "");  
user_pref("print.print_footerright", "");`

Comment: to fix the print background i ended up finding:  `user_pref("print.print_bgcolor", true);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found all the answers and will post them here just in case others need this info:

Add the following lines to the default prefs.js file

`user_pref("print.print_headerleft", "");

    user_pref("print.print_headercenter", "");

    user_pref("print.print_headerright", "");

    user_pref("print.print_footerleft", "");

    user_pref("print.print_footercenter", "");

    user_pref("print.print_footerright", "");

    user_pref("print.print_bgcolor", true);`

You could also modify the default margins using the below

`user_pref("print.print_margin_bottom", "0.4");

    user_pref("print.print_margin_left", "0.4");

    user_pref("print.print_margin_right", "0.4");

    user_pref("print.print_margin_top", "0.4");`